# Generic entity save method not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

In an attempt to reduce the amount of code and classes I use I have been given this method:

```
public TEntity Save(TEntity entity)
            {
                var validatationErrors = Entities.GetValidationErrors().ToList();
                if (validatationErrors.Count() > 0)
                    throw new ValidateException(validatationErrors);

                if (Entities.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Added)
                    Entities.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
                else
                    Entities.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity);

                Entities.SaveChanges();
                Entities.Entry(entity).Reload();
                return entity;
            }
```

When I create a new Product however it skips the conditional that would Add it to the database. Therefore not getting saved. Same is if I try to modify something it doesn't change.

To remedy this I have to save my entities in the controller like so:

```
using (var db = new EntitiesDbContext())
                {
                    db.Products.Attach(product);
                    db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
```

This seems rather inefficient.
So I was wondering really what's wrong with the generic save that makes it not work?

Comment: Have you set the state to Added/Modified? That is, is `Entities.Entry(entity).State` == `EntityState.Added` or `EntityState.Modified`?

Comment: Where would I set this? I'm currently setting it from the controller action but that seems very inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

- Your code is wrong. In your case you don't need to `Attach` your entities. You just need to `Add` your entity to your `DbSet`:

  ```
          public TEntity Save(TEntity entity)
          {
              Entities.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);        
              Entities.SaveChanges();
          }
  ```

You should remember:

`Entities.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);`

equals to

`db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;`

and

`entity.Property = newProperty;`

set entity state to `Modified` (`db.Entry(entity).State` is  `EntityState.Modified`)

And you don't need to validate and reload entity. `ObjectContext` do it for you.

- To conditionalize your entity try this:

  ```
      public TEntity Save(TEntity entity)
      {

          var dbEntity = Entities.Set<TEntity>().Find(entity.Id);

          if (dbEntity != null)               
              dbEntity = entity;
          else
              Entities.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);

          Entities.SaveChanges();
      }
  ```

Comment: How would I properly conditionalize the add? Because without a condition you would add a new instance of the entity when you edit it.

Comment: Alright, but since it's generic you can't pull an Id out of the entity since you don't actually know which entity it is. And pulling the entire entity `Entities.Set<TEntity>().Find(entity);` isn't allowed.

Comment: You can inherit your Entity classes from one base class and write this: "public class YourClassThatContainSaveMethod<TEntity> where TEntity : BaseClass" and use base class Id. Or you can do something like this: "public TEntity Save(TEntity entity, int id)"

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new entity you should use .Add method. .Attach should be used if you have an object that you know it exists in the database and you want to avoid a trip to the database to get it.

Also the generic Save method seems to have a few problems:

- unless you disabled validation explicitly you will validate entities more than once since by default .SaveChanges() will validate entities
- if an entity is in Added state it is already being tracked by the context and therefore there is no need to add it again
- .SaveChanges() will try to save all entities tracked by the context that are not in Unchanged state. The method makes an impression that it will save only the entity you passed but in fact it may save more than that
- I think invoking DbEntityEntry.Reload() makes sense only for attached entities to update property values with values from the database - if you do this always then I am wondering why you attach the entity rather than just getting it from the database.

Comment: Right. So there is an .Add method, but the EntityState.Added conditional is skipped over. The method doesn't save extra stuff, it saves nothing at all. Ideally though a save method should be able to handle both creation and updating. But I agree that there's something wrong with the design. I'm just not sure how to make it create new entities and update edited entities.

Comment: If you have a new entity use just Enities.Set<TEntity>().Add(). If you modified entity properties and the entity is tracked (i.e. you first got it from the database) you don't have to do anything. EF should discover that it was modified and the changes (along with new entities) should be saved to the database when you call .SaveChanges(). Honestly, I am not sure I would use the generic method.

Comment: So you think creating a save method for each entity would be the wiser thing to do?

Comment: I don't think you need this method. You may want to just create a generic method for getting the right DbSet based on the type of the entity to be able to add/attach the entity to the set but I doubt that you need this as well since you can use the other overload of DbContext.Set that takes type. I don't have the full picture of what you are trying to do but in general you should just get entities from the database (if needed) modify and/or add and/or delete entities based on your needs. Call SaveChanges to persist all the changes rather than just for single entity (it would save all anyways)